# Warning: Not annotated parameter overrides @NotNull parameter for Comparable implementation

Tags: java

I implement the `Comparable` interface and I get the warning for the parameter in `compareTo` overridden method:

```
@Data
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
    private Long id;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Item other) {
        if (this.id != null && other.id != null) {
            return (int) (this.id - other.id);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

> Warning: Not annotated parameter overrides @NotNull parameter

There is a thread on https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000214479-External-annotations-Not-annotated-parameter-overrides-NotNull-parameter, but it's outdated and you have to dig into it to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your warning it's telling that parent class method has @NotNull or @NonNull annotated parameter. To fix that issue you need to use same annotation on your overridden method.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(@NotNull final Item other) {
    // Logic goes here
}

OR

@Override
public int compareTo(@NonNull final Item other) {
    // Logic goes here
}
```

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it's because the overridden method has a not null annotation! The warning is unclear to me, thx.

Answer (score 1):

Annotate the parameter with one of the not null

```
import jakarta.annotation.Nonnull;

public int compareTo(@Nonnull final Item other) {
```